# For which integral values of $x$ is $|x^2-9|$ a prime number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For which integral values of $x$ is $|x^2-9|$ a prime number?

Does anyone have any idea what an integral value means?

I solved this problem by ignoring the word and i get $x=2,4$ because the outcome would be $5,7$ which is odd but anybody have any other ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Integral values means integer values, so $-2$ and $-4$ are also allowed. For proof, our expression is $|x-3||x+3|$, so one of $|x-3|$ or $|x+3|$ must be $1$ and the other prime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $|x^2 -9| = |x - 3||x + 3|$. This is composite whenever neither factor is trivial (i.e. 1). Therefore $|x^2 - 9|$ is prime precisely when $|x - 3| = 1$ or $|x + 3| = 1$. This gives $x = \pm 2, \pm 4$.